# Why PayPal is redirecting to return page without query strings?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have two files index.php and success.php like this:

[image]

index.php contains:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Paypal test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  
      <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="zuhair.53957-facilitator@gmail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="item">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/paypal/success.php"> 
        <button type="submit">pay now</button>
      </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

and success.php contains:

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

When I click on "pay now" button it goes to PayPal, But after successful transaction it redirect to success.php without query strings like this:

[image]

Why there is no query strings at the return page?

Comment: my solve after testing: I logged into my sandbox account -> profile -> my selling tools -> Website preferences (update) -> Return URL and set my return page url. After that, it worked will

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Paypal test</title>
   </head>
   <body>

  <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="zuhair.53957-
     facilitator@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="item">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" 
    value="http://localhost/paypal/success.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1"> 
    <button type="submit">pay now</button>
  </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

I have added the value of rm and you can refer [the values here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/).

rm stands for Return method. The FORM METHOD used to send data to the URL specified by the return variable.

Valid value is:

1. All shopping cart payments use the GET method.
2. The buyer's browser is redirected to the return URL by using the GET method, but no payment variables are included.
3. The buyer's browser is redirected to the return URL by using the POST method, and all payment variables are included.

Comment: I tried your code, but this appears: Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later.

Comment: Try changing the localhost url as :                                                          
          <input type="hidden" name="return" 
           value="http:// <Your IP Address>  /paypal/success.php">

Comment: I changed to ip, then I tried it on a real website. but the same problem still exist.

Comment: Can you list the code you are currently testing with?

Comment: Also change amount to input to                                                                                             <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">

Comment: I logged into my sandbox account -> profile -> my selling tools -> Website preferences (update) -> Return URL and set my return page url. After that, it worked will.